# BootstrapX popover and close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm developing Joomla 2.5 site with template based on Twitter Bootstrap v2.1.1.

I'm also using BootstrapX - clickover, a Bootstrap extension to allow popovers to be opened and closed with clicks on elements instead of hover or focus: https://github.com/lecar-red/bootstrapx-clickover.

In popover I'm calling a HTML file with simple AJAX currency converter.

This is HTML which triggers popover with currency converter:

```
<a class="pretvornik withajaxpopover" href="#" rel="clickover" title="Pretvornik valut" data-load="http://www.cheaperandmore.com/files/static_converter.html">Click here</a>
```

This is content of the HTML  file (http://www.cheaperandmore.com/files/static_converter.html):

```
<p>V okence vpišite znesek v britanskih funtih, ki ga želite preračunati v eure.</p>
<div id="currencyBox">
    <div class="currencyInner">
        <div class="data">
            <input type="text" name="znesek" id="znesek" value="1" /><span id="gbpsign">&pound;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <select name="fromCurrency" id="fromCurrency">
                <option selected="" value="GBP">GBP</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <select name="toCurrency" id="toCurrency">
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="currencyInner" id="calcresults"></div>

    <div class="clr">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="data">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="convert" id="convert" value="Pretvori &raquo;" />
        <button class="btn" class="clickover" data-toggle='button' data-dismiss="clickover">Zapri</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Add close button to bootstrap popovers
$('[rel="clickover"]').clickover();

//Load data
$('.withajaxpopover').bind('click',function(){
    var el=$(this);
    $.get(el.attr('data-load'),function(d){
        el.unbind('click').popover({content: d}).popover('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Right now when I click on a link which triggers popover, two popovers appear.

One popover has content from static_converter.html, but it's missing clickover class "popover fade right in".
Other popover, which is hidden behind first one has correct class "popover clickover fade right in", but it has no content except title which is taken from a.pretvornik.withajaxpower title tag.

So when I click close button in the first popover it actually closes second popover (because it has clickover class).
I can't figure out what I'm I doing wrong.

You can see it here: http://www.cheaperandmore.com (click on the "£ » €" in the first semicircle in the top left part of the page).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the plugin is inheriting from the Twitter Bootstrap popover plugin : it means you don't need to call `.clickover()` if you call `.popover()` (or rather the opposite).

You should try that

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Load data and bind clickover
$('.withajaxpopover').on('click.ajaxload',function(){
    var el=$(this);
    $.get(el.attr('data-load'),function(d){
        el.off('click.ajaxload').clickover({content: d}).clickover('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

I took the liberty of changing `bind` and `unbind` to `on` and `off` because it's [preferred since 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

I also added an [event name](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) `click.ajaxload` to avoid conflict, but you should look into [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) because it does the unbinding for you.

---

If you have clickovers that don't have the ajax loading part, you should make two separate selectors and enable the clickover plugin differently on each.

You can for example remove the `rel="clickover"` attribute on the `.withajaxpopover` elements, and keep both `$('[rel="clickover"]').clickover();` and the code above.

Comment: Although we decided to drop this functionality, I tried proposed solution from @Sherbrow and it works with only one issue. Close button works only after clicking on trigger selector first. After that it works normally.

I removed